# c++ Array MEMMOVE bug

Tags: c++, arrays, string

So, what I want to do is placing a 'p' before all vowels, I'm doing that but because of the memmove, the char array is filled with strange symbols.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include <cstring>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s1[256];
    cin.get(s1,255);
    cin.get();
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s1);i++)
    {
        if(strchr("aeiou",s1[i])){
            memmove(s1+i+1,s1+i,strlen(s1));
            // duplicating the vowel so i can replace it
            s1[i]='p';
            i++;            
        }
    }
    cout<<s1;
    getch();
return 0;
}
```

Input : oaie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your memmove call, you are using the incorrect length:

```
memmove(s1+i+1,s1+i,strlen(s1));
```

`strlen(s1)` is the length of the string starting from the beginning and not including the null terminator. So there are two problems. First, you want the length of the string starting from the current position. Second, you want the length *including* the null terminator, so that the null terminator gets copied.

The result of these bugs is that if the first character is a vowel then the `memove` will over-write the null terminator and additional garbage in the buffer will start being processed as if it were part of your string.

Additionally `memove` will access outside the buffer given certain input and garbage in the buffer.

The solution is to use the correct length, `strlen(s1+i)`, and to include the null terminator:

```
memmove(s1+i+1,s1+i,strlen(s1+i)+1);
```

---

`cin.get(s1, 255)` does store a null terminator, and in fact you can safely give it the correct buffer size: `cin.get(s1, 256)`.

---

using `std::string` you can avoid these sorts of mistakes:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s1;
    std::getline(std::cin, s1);

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.size(); ++i) {
        if (std::strchr("aeiou", s1[i])) {
            s1.insert(i, "p");
            ++i;
        }
    }
    std::cout << s1 << '\n';
}
```

Note that this doesn't have any fixed buffer size, doesn't have to give special consideration to null terminators, doesn't have to figure out how many bytes need moving, and directly expresses the intent to "insert 'p' at this location".

Comment: So the third memmove parameter should be the current strating position not the string length?

Comment: @user4749795: The third parameter is the number of bytes to copy. This answer explains it well, you should read it.

Comment: @user4749795 imagine the string is 10 bytes long (including the null terminator) and you're processing the 5th character: when you perform the move, you want to move the last 5 bytes to make room for the 'p'. But using the length of the whole string will move 10 bytes including 5 bytes that are not part of the string and which may be outside the buffer.